# Using Cassandra Prepared Statement using Cassandra Operations Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

I need Prepared Statement / instead of Query Builder using  Cassandra Operations Interface and session 
Any Example or recent docs. for Cassandra using java

Comment: Are you `spring data cassandra` ?

Comment: yes Ajit Using Spring Data Cassandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spring-data-cassandra v1.x, the **getSession()** method of [org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cassandra/core/CqlOperations.html#getSession--) could let you access **Session** directly. However, similar APIs are deprecated since v2.0

Here is a example from [https://github.com/opencredo/spring-data-cassandra-example/](https://github.com/opencredo/spring-data-cassandra-example/blob/master/src/test/java/example/CqlTemplateIntegrationTest.java)

```
@Autowired
private CqlOperations cqlTemplate;//or inherited interface, like CassandraOperations

private void insertEventUsingPreparedStatement() {
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cqlTemplate.getSession().prepare("insert into event (id, type, bucket, tags) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  Statement insertStatement = preparedStatement.bind(UUIDs.timeBased(), "type2", TIME_BUCKET, ImmutableSet.of("tag1", "tag2"));
  cqlTemplate.execute(insertStatement); 
}
```

Comment: Need to query a table with where clause which gives object of a particular row using CassandraOperations or CqlTemplate interface The above cqlTemplate.execute(insertStatement); returns void

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/statements/prepared/) to check how to use prepared statment while using java datastax driver.

However i would recommend to store all preparedstatments in a cache (for example a map) while application initializes and reuse the same whenever requreid by creating boundstatment out of it.
For example :

```
//Here Key is query string 
 private static final Map<String, PreparedStatement> psMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PreparedStatement>();

 //Will be invoked @ initialization 
 public void init(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        for (QuerySetEnum cql : QuerySetEnum.values()) {

            psMap.put(cql.getStatement(), session.prepare(cql.getStatement()));
        }


        //In Dao Impl class 
        //Get bounded statment + execute by passing the value
         @Override
    public void decreaseStats(long size, long count, String mapname,
            int bucketId) {
        BoundStatement boundStatement = getBoundStatement(QuerySetEnum.DECREASE_STATS);
        metaTemplate.execute(boundStatement.bind(size, count, mapname,
                bucketId));

    }
//Below is the implementation how to get BoundStatement out to prepared statment cache
    private BoundStatement getBoundStatement(QuerySetEnum query) {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = queryPool
                .getPreparedStatement(query);
        BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(preparedStatement);
        return boundStatement;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spring-data-cassandra and that will do all magic for you.
App sample https://github.com/valchkou-app/spring-boot-cassandra-simple

```
@Repository
interface ISensorMeasureRepository extends CassandraRepository<SensorMeasureEntity> {

  @Query('select * from sensor_measures_simple where sensor_id=?0 and measure_time>=?1 and measure_time<=?2')
  List<SensorMeasureEntity> getBySensorAndDateRange(int sensorId, Date start, Date end)

  @Query('select * from sensor_measures_simple where sensor_id=?0 ALLOW FILTERING')
  Stream<SensorMeasureEntity> getAllBySensor(int sensorId)
}
```

Comment: Hey , thanks ... Is @Query annotation making use of prepared statement or a raw cql query ?